# why downloading image from url returns nil?

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimage

I am trying to download an image that is uploaded to my database storage and the link to the image is in my Real time database. There is no problem with the link but when I use my method to return the image from the link I am getting nil. I force wrap it because it needs to return an image for now.

This is my code:

```
func getImageFromUrl(url: URL) -> UIImage {
    var tempImage: UIImage? = nil

    print("INSIDE URL -> \(url.absoluteString)")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
       if error != nil {
           print("Error on getImageFromUrl : \(error!.localizedDescription)")
           return
       }

       print("Image data " + data.debugDescription)

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           tempImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
           print("TEMP IMAGE > \(String(describing: tempImage?.images![0]))")
       }
    }.resume()

    if tempImage == nil {
        print("IMAGE IS NIL!")
    }
    return tempImage!
 }
```

Please let me know why my code is failing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24231680/2303865

Comment: the download method is asynchronous. You are returning the result before the download process is completed. What you need is to add a completion handler to your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the dataTask method is asynchronous. You are returning the result before the download process is completed. What you need is to add a completion handler to your method to return the image or the error once finished:

---

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func getImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> ()) {
    print("download started:", url.absoluteString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, reponse, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        print("download finished:")
        completion(UIImage(data: data), nil)
    }.resume()
}
```

---

```
let url = URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/varL9.jpg")!
getImage(from: url) { image, error in
    guard let image = image else {
        print("error:", error ?? "")
        return
    }
    print("image size:", image.size)
    // use your image here and don't forget to always update the UI from the main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the following code but I am getting this error:  The requested URL was not found on this server. I can se see the URL is on my Firebase database. What could this be?

Comment: Show your url. Have you tested it in your desktop browser? What happens?

Comment: If I copy and paste my url in the browser it automatically downloads a jpg. This is the url -> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/the-spot-6bdd6.appspot.com/o/user%2FnC2ayJaTVSOe5qUXWOCJ1ILbIuT2%2F1%2F0.jpg?alt=media&token=789d3875-789f-4691-806f-404782b19252

Comment: Just pasted your link in my playground and it printed  `"image size: (3072.0, 2304.0)\n"`

Comment: Try using the UIImageView extension I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/2303865

Comment: Hum ok thank you I will try it.

Comment: I am getting this error {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}

Comment: Check if you are using the proper token

Comment: Your link is expired. try clicking the link you posted above `{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}`

Comment: It is returning a json string instead of an image

Comment: How is it expiring if I am uploading and downloading after I upload.